# What does shadow /V actually do?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services

According to `shadow`:

```
C:\Users\mark.henderson>shadow /?
Monitor another Remote Desktop Services session.

SHADOW {sessionname | sessionid} [/SERVER:servername] [/V]

  sessionname         Identifies the session with name sessionname.
  sessionid           Identifies the session with ID sessionid.
  /SERVER:servername  The server containing the session (default is current).
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
```

`/V` is meant to `Display information about actions being performed.` But for the life of me, I cannot get this flag to do anything. [Technet is no more helpful](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772355%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) than the above text; and [neither is google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=shadow%20/v&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=7bU&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22shadow%20/v%22&oq=%22shadow%20/v%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30l4.2966.3540.0.3741.2.2.0.0.0.0.422.422.4-1.1.0...0.0...1c.LBhXNnKEpPo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=32e3dafab79fa996&biw=1920&bih=923).

Performing, say `shadow 3 /server:myts1.example.com /V` just shadows the account normally.

Comment: So far as I can tell it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried piping the command to a `.txt` file?  I did and ended up with an empty .txt file, so I'm leaning towards "nothing," but that's maybe something worth trying out (I don't trust my environment to behave normally, so someone should verify that behavior).

Comment: Although it says "display..." I'd check the event logs and see if anything extra is being put in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description seems a bit off.

The correct command is:

> shadow /V [n]

Where [n] is actually a session number.

> shadow /V 1

The above would remotely connect you to a session 1. The session number can be found under the User tabs from Task Manager.

A prompt would appear on the session and request the user to either accept or decline the remote control.

[image: Remote control request]

Comment: I'm so sorry for not following up on this earlier! I didn't see your answer come past for some reason. This explains a lot, thanks!